# Part of drop-down menu is not visible

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, nav

I am trying to create drop-down menu, but when I add `position: absolute;` and `display: block;`, I can't see all of the second `ul` element . I want to see both `ul` elements, so I can then add a `hover` and a `display` and complete the drop-down menu.

I tried using `z-index` and `overflow`, but nothing worked.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: #1C1B1A;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

header nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header nav h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 350;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 5rem;
}

header nav .links {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #6B653C;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-right: 5rem;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2.75rem 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(2.75rem 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

header nav .links ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav .links ul li {
  margin: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

header nav .links ul li ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2rem;
  background: #6B653C;
}

header nav .links ul li ul li {
  margin-left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1>logo</h1>
      <div class="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ji-nov-ek/pen/KKWMawG

Comment: This won't work with clip-path. `header nav .links { clip-path: polygon (2.75rem 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); }`. Only use this cut off on the left side [example](https://jsfiddle.net/danielpietrasik/3roc6j8L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simplified code, because yours is a big mess ;)
You're making the code too complicated. For example, use the wrong `font-weight: 350` fonts, but there are only hundreds in `googleapis.com` decalaration.
And why do you need so many versions of the fonts, [100,200, ..., 900] after all, it slows down the page incredibly. You can use html `strong` or `b` elements.

```css
:root {
  --olive: #6b653c;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #1c1b1a;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  height: 78px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.links {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: var(--olive);
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.links:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid var(--olive);
}

.links ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.links ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  background: var(--olive);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-menu:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>logo</h1>
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">link</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>last</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```